# How can I write and read consistently in the W5500's registers using the EK-TM4C123GXL with SPI communication?

Tags: spi, communication, tm4c123g

I used a modified code from an example for SPI communication "spiloopback" from Texas Instruments, where I tried to write data in the registers of [W5500](https://gr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/443/Wiznet_W5500_DS_1%200%205-1212109.pdf) and then read those data.

[image]

```c
uint8_t masterRxBuffer1[SPI_MSG_LENGTH];
uint8_t masterTxBuffer1[SPI_MSG_LENGTH] = {0x00, 0x26, 0x14, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00,0x00};
uint8_t masterRxBuffer2[SPI_MSG_LENGTH];
uint8_t masterTxBuffer2[SPI_MSG_LENGTH] = {0x00, 0x26, 0x16, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,0x00};
uint8_t slaveRxBuffer1[SPI_MSG_LENGTH];
uint8_t slaveTxBuffer1[SPI_MSG_LENGTH];
uint8_t slaveRxBuffer2[SPI_MSG_LENGTH];
uint8_t slaveTxBuffer2[SPI_MSG_LENGTH];
```

Block Select Bits = 00010
MODE              = 00
Offset Address    = 0x0026
Written data      = 3 x 0xFF

In the oscilloscope:

- 1st signal = clock
- 2nd signal = MOSI
- 3rd signal = CS/SS
- 4th signal = MISO

It worked somewhat but it was very inconsistent, by that I mean that every time I reset the board I get a different read and I don't know why.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[W5500 datasheet](https://gr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/443/Wiznet_W5500_DS_1%200%205-1212109.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

The Read command doesn't seem to correspond with the write command.

[image]

Write Command: **0x14**

- BSB[4:0] = 00010 (Selects Socket 0 TX Buffer)
- RWB = 1 (Write)
- OM[1:0] = 00 (Variable Data Length Mode, N-Bytes Data Phase (1 ≤ N))

Read Command: **0x16**

- BSB[4:0] = 00010 (Selects Socket 0 TX Buffer)
- RWB = **1 (Write)**
- OM[1:0] = **10** (Fixed Data Length Mode , 2 Byte Data Length (N = 2))

I imagine the correct Read Command to be: **0x10**

- BSB[4:0] = 00010 (Selects Socket 0 TX Buffer)
- RWB = ***0 (Read)***
- OM[1:0] = ***00*** (Variable Data Length Mode, N-Bytes Data Phase (1 ≤ N))*

Image taken from the [Datasheet](https://www.mouser.ch/datasheet/2/443/Wiznet_W5500_DS_1%200%205-1212109.pdf).